# Open Flash Chart 2 IE doesn't load new data for chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, internet-explorer

I have OFC2 chart in my page and when user selectes choice, then it will make another request to server with parameters and OFC2 should load new data from server, but IE won't load new data, but it shos old data instead. It works well in other browsers, but not in IE. What could be the problem here, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

i too have same issue, i have develop the dashboard which refresh and get data for every 5min. but IE always take old data only. i even try to clear the cache, but no use.

Finally, once i change the delay to 20 min, data got refresh without any problem. 
So please try to extend your relay timing, hope it work.

Answer (score 0):

look at this entry:
[why-would-my-updated-flash-chart-not-be-refreshing-in-internet-exp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343687/rails-flash-why-would-my-updated-flash-chart-not-be-refreshing-in-internet-exp)

It worked for me (just add a different random extra parameter every time you refresh your page)

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because of an IE caching issue. I believe IE is caching the requests that the OFC code uses. To work around this, add a random parameter to the request each time. For example if you are currently requesting `http://myserver.com/script.php?userid=1` then request `http://myserver.com/script.php?userid=1&randomparam=<some_random_number_here>`